# CXF-generated SOAP client: no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl

Tags: java, wsdl2java, cxf-codegen-plugin

I generated SOAP client stub with CXF 3.4.2 codegen Maven plugin.
However, when trying to create the service stub created, I get a bunch of errors like that:

```
There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {http://tempuri.org/}travelDocumentNumber.
this problem is related to the following location:
    at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement org.tempuri.GetActiveVisasForArrival.travelDocumentNumber
    at org.tempuri.GetActiveVisasForArrival
```

However, there is an object factory containing the following code:

```
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", name = "travelDocumentNumber", scope = GetActiveVisasForArrival.class)
public JAXBElement<String> createGetActiveVisasForArrivalTravelDocumentNumber(String value) {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(_GetActiveVisasForArrivalTravelDocumentNumber_QNAME, String.class, GetActiveVisasForArrival.class, value);
}
```

As I can see, such error comes with every parameter of WS interface method (excluding XMLGregorianCalendar) and every returning value.

How can I get rid of those errors?

I generate the code this way:

```
                    <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>./generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>./src/main/resources/wsdl/evisa.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <serviceName>BorderManagementSystemService</serviceName>
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
```

How I initialize the service:

```
service = (IBorderManagementSystemService) new BorderManagementSystemService(new URL(WSDL_LOCATION)).getBasicHttpBindingIBorderManagementSystemService();
```

The WSDL file was exposed by some C# web service. I used single WSDL option; however, generating from root WSDL causes same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have added mapping for namespaces to unique Java packages in the plugin parameters and now things work. Probably there was a conflict with other clients generated code.

```
<extraarg>-p</extraarg>                                                                    
<extraarg>http://tempuri.org/=rw.gov.dgie.gk.integration.evisa.client</extraarg>           
<extraarg>-p</extraarg> 
<extraarg>http://schemas.migration.gov.rw/evisa=rw.gov.dgie.gk.integration.evisa</extraarg>
```